# What is the necessity of "export default connect" when you are connecting your react component to redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was trying to create some components in the same jsx file. I wants to connect one of the child component to store(feels wrong here), without connecting the HOC component to the store.
Therefore when connecting the child component he does not use **export default connect**. It creates an error saying **actions** are undefined.

Example code.

```
class Test1 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   ****
   } 
   render(){
   ****
   }
}
function mapActionsToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
       actions: {
          testAction: bindActionCreators(testActionFromActions, dispatch)
       }
   }
connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) (Test1);

class Test2 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
   ***
   }
   render(){
      return (<Test1/>);
   }
}

export default Test2;
```

My question is why we always need to use **connect** as **export default connect** ?. Is there any other ways to do the connect?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ```connect``` as the name sounds connects your components with your Redux store. You can not connect/interact your component without the connect method of redux. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Adeel Imran. Yes it does.

Comment: Connect does not always have to be a export default connect. You can use a named export too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

connect() returns a new connected component.
In fact, connect() wraps your component in a new one, adding some useful features, that is why you usually export the return value of the connect function (the new component).

In your case, you should do something like

```
class Test1 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   ****
   } 
   render(){
   ****
   }
}
function mapActionsToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
       actions: {
          testAction: bindActionCreators(testActionFromActions, dispatch)
       }
   }
const ConnectedTest1 = connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) (Test1);

class Test2 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
   ***
   }
   render(){
      return (<ConnectedTest1/>);
   }
}

export default Test2;
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: In other words it will let the component to have the props and the action. Mapping them

Comment: const ConnectedTest1 should include mapDispatchToProps not mapActionsToProps if I'm not mistaken :)

Comment: Thanks this helped me!
BTW I did this :: `export { ConnectedTest1 as Test1 }`  
Without using another component :)

Answer (score 6):

With a little bit of more researching I found a cure :D.

connect always returns a function. In my given example I input Test1 as an argument to the connect function.

So we need to assign the returned function to some **variable** or **const**. In the above example the line **connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) (Test1);** should change to  **const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) (Test1);**. After that I can export the component(ConnectedComponent) or reuse it within the same file.

[this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/647) link help me to understand this.

Hope this answer will help others.

Comment: you can use the code below to export.
`const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,mapActionsToProps) (Test1);`
`export {ConnectedComponent  as Test1} `